# Why determine object type in .NET?

Tags: c#

Why do we need to determine the type of an object using `Type.GetType()` or `typeof`

Comment: The question is why do YOU need this ?

Comment: Can you provide more context and/or a sample what you are trying to accomplish? Or is your question what the difference between `GetType` and `typeof` is? Then just search this site as this question already has been answered.

Comment: Uhhh... because that's how the C# team made it, and you can't do it any other way?

Comment: I'm still waiting for the `obj.HelloKindlyWhatAreYouExactly()` method...

Comment: yes i wanted to know why do we need this???

Comment: I got the typeobject T, what is the use of the getting the typeobject like this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're asking why get an object's type information, not why do we get it using the syntax in your question.

Type information is often useful when used with [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxz4wk15%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Without further context it's hard to answer this fully.

Answer (score 0):

One usage is getting list of the object properties, at run time:

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties();
```

There are other cases when it's useful, without more details we can't really tell what is relevant  to you.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is well designed, you should rarely need them.

To me, most of the time it's a code smell: if you need to know the object's type, then something's wrong in your hierarchy. Pay attention that "most of the time" doesn't mean  "always", take it as a guideline.